# Working with multiuser / multimachine setup with Visual Studio and Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

first of all I'm new to VS2017 and GIT (I used VS2008 and SourceSafe before, SubVersion also).

I was able to set up my own git server (Bonbo) and it works nicely.

I was able (after some fiddling) to get a project published on it using VS2017. Including commits and anything.

But:
If I want to open the project on a new machine, I ran into troubles.

I don't see a way to open a git repository in VS directly. I have read I need to download the project and open this. Well, ok, done.

At this point, I am able to edit the project and maybe create a local repository for it.

But how can I commit changes from this 2nd machine to the repository? I can't sync, on incoming commits, it says:

> Der aktuelle Branch überwacht keinen Remotebranch" which means

roughly translated

> "The current branch does not monitor a remote branch".

Under changes all files are flagged as added.

If I make a local push it works (locally). But if I try to sync I get:

```
Error: failed to push some refs to 'https://*************'
Error: hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
 hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
 hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
 hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I'm really stuck right now...

Answer (score 0):

Oof this is a pretty difficult thing to explain in a textbox :).

Let us decompose the problems:

### 1. How do I create a local copy of a Git repository on new machine.

This process is called cloning. You'd use the Clone option in Visual studio or from the commandline would issue a `git clone location.of.your.remote.repository` command.

This will create a local copy of the repository with all the data and branches in it.

### 2. How do I sync my changes

In Git you first commit the changes to a local repository before sending them onward to a central or remote repository for sharing (in theory you could send them directly to your peer as well). This happens through "pushing" your changes. By default your changes will be pushed to a branch with the same name as your local branch, unless you've configured it differently (by setting the "upstream" branch").

Your first error "Der aktuelle Branch überwacht keinen Remotebranch" can be solved either by:

- publishing the branch, which will create a branch with the same name on the remote and push the changes (the Sync panel in Visual Studio will have a Publish option)
- merging the changes from the local branch into a branch tracking a branch that already exists on the remote branch and pushing that instead.
- pushing the changes directly to the remote branch from the commandline `git push remote-name target-branch-name`.

After a successful push to the remote you can then "pull" these changes to another machine.

### 3. How do I get up-to-date with the remote

As you've already come across, Git will prevent you from accidentally overwriting changes on the remote branch. You need to locally resolve the conflicts before you can push new changes. Even if you local changes have touched files that are untouched on the remote, it will require you to sync first.

First save all your changes locally. And commit those changes. Then you perform a "pull" to receive the changes from the remote. Git will force a merge if needed. After resolving these merge conflicts you can push you locally merged changes back to the remote.

There are alternative options here too that are more advanced patterns.

### Note

The Sync button is a bit of a bad thing. It tries to do too many things at once. By default "sync" will try to perform: "fetch" followed by "pull" immediately followed by "push". It's a good practice to do these steps separately until you really know what you're doing.

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction with this, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working *yay*

Steps to make it:

1. Either download the .zip from git server and extract it or use "git clone https://YourServer.tld/YourProject.git" in the target directory. Lets say it becomes "C:\Git\MyProject"
2. Open VS2017. In the TeamExplorer add an existing local repository. Point to the directory created in #1.
3. Double-click on the local repository entry. The repository start page shows up.
4. Go to Repository Settings. Validate the remotes. They should point to your remote server (https://YourServer.tld/YourProject.git").
5. Go back to home and select Branches. You see the local branch (master) as well as "remotes/origin". Expand this node and right click on the "master" inside of it. Select Fetch. Don't know if this is required, just to be sure.
6. Back in home you see the solution file. Double-click to open it.

From now on you can make your changes.

7. After done (still in home page), click on Changes, enter a commit description (like "Fixed typos") and Commit and Push.

Maybe there are several other ways, like jessehouwing said. Creating it as new branch and so on, but this was what I was looking for, as a beginner. :)

Many thanks :)